# Overring a base class @property while still allowing the base class to access it

Tags: objective-c, oop

I don't think that what I want to do is possible, but there are people here that are more cunning than myself, so I thought I'd ask anyway....

Imagine we have a class A:

```
@interface A
@property (strong) NSArray *items;
// There'll be methods and stuff too
@end
```

Now, we need a drop in replacement for this class to change some behavioral aspects:

```
@interface B : A
@property (strong) NSArray *items;
// There'll be methods and stuff too
@end
```

In particular, we override the "items" property since we need it to return something different.

That works well until a method called on an instance of B, which is implemented in A and not overridden by B, tries to access "self.items". Rather than access it's own copy, it accesses B's overridden version and thus sees unexpected results - and indeed crashes the app in my real case :(

I can solve this by renaming the property in B - but then this is no longer a drop in replacement, and that's a shame.

Note that class B can access A's version of the property via super. Ideally any access to the property from class A would also access A's version of it. Any suggestions? In my getter is there a way to know who's requesting it, for example?

Tim

Comment: When you say "a method in class A tries to access", I think that you are talking about a method called on an instance of B, which is implemented in A and not overridden by B. Is that right? There's no way that an instance of A would be using B's accessors.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do what you're trying to do.  By overriding the variable/method in a subclass, all instances of that class will use the method appropriate to that class, not where the calling method resides.

Comment: Josh - yes, I've updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: You say you want it to return two different things for the two implementations - does that mean that it is a read-only property? Because if it is a read-write property, I would expect it to return whatever it has been set to, and hence no need to re-define it. This may be an extra restriction that I lay over the formal definition, though.

Comment: No, it's not read only. I was just hoping that there was a way to stop A from picking up the overridden property and to have it continue to access it's own copy instead.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to figure out how you can solve the specific problem you're having.  What Apple class are you subclassing, and what property of that class do you want to override, and for what purpose?

Comment: I take that back - the base class's property is read only - which is annoying because I had a plan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically achieve what you want, but in a horrid round-about hack. Put this sort of thing into your production code at your own peril and don't expect any sympathy if it all falls apart.

Don't make `B` a subclass of `A`, make it merely a class that has an `A`. Implement those methods on `B` that you would otherwise have replaced in the subclass anyway. For dealing with `items`, make sure that `B`'s `setItems:` makes an appropriate corresponding call to `A` — indeed make that the case for all methods you override but which you wish would also communicate something to `A`.

Then create a class `C` which has a `B` and an `A`. Don't implement anything on it. Follow the normal convention that `alloc` and `init` return `(id)` and perform the slightly odd task of:

```
A *instance = [[C alloc] init];
```

On `C` implement only your preferred forwarding logic:

```
@implementation C

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if([self.instanceOfB respondsToSelector:aSelector]) return self.instanceOfB;
    return self.instanceOfA.
}

@end
```

Now every references `A` makes to `self` is a reference to an instance of `A` rather than a subclass. Nevertheless you have an instance of `B` in the system and it will act as though it inherits from `A` by getting any messages that the relevant instance of `A` would have serviced in preference to it, while being able to defer whatever it wants to up to `A`.

By giving those classes that would have had an instance of `A` an instance of `C`, they'll go through your unique inheritance logic rather than the default stuff. Furthermore, because you've returned `(id)` in the appropriate place and both are objects, it's a safe implicit cast and the compiler won't complain that you keep calling methods on `C` that aren't implemented.

Comment: Clever. In my case it's even simpler, just having A as an instance of B solves everything - its 's blatantly obvious! Thanks for the inspiration, TAFetchedResultsController (on GitHub) is now much better off for you intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing, but anyway...

Overriding a method/property doesn't change it globally; it changes it only for the class which does the overriding. If an instance of A accesses the property, it would still access its own property, it won't be magically taken over by the subclass' implementation.

(By the way, let me mention that your class is probably very badly designed if you need such a behavior...)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I'm referring to method called on an instance of B, which is implemented in A and not overridden by B. Said method apparently access "self.items" at some point, and in doing so retrieves my overridden version - I'd like it to carry on getting it's own instead. Class A is written by Apple - I can't change that :)

Comment: If you are calling it on an instance of `B` even if the method is only implemented in `A`, it should always use `B`'s `items` object

Comment: Yes, but I'm hoping there's a cunning way to stop that from happening, such as returning A's own copy if I know that A's requesting it.

Comment: Then why not simply use `super.myProperty`?

Comment: I can from a method implemented in B. However, there's a method implement by A that calls self.items, and in doing to is retrieves the items property that I'm overriding. I don't want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well overriding the property in B means that any accessors in B will access the new property in B. The behavior of A remains unchanged, accessors in A will always access the original property in A. A class can not and should never be aware of it's sublasses.

If you want the subclass to continue to accesss the super classes property you can't override it. Period.

Also note that a property (or an accessor to it) must be declared in the interface (fundamentaly making it public) for its copy to be directly accessible in subclasses. That's necessary since there is no such thing as a 'protected property' in Objective-C.

Lastly let's say you put classes of type A, B or even C in a bag and then forget their types, just know that all share an is-a relationship, then you can use dynamic binding / introspection to decide which class's method will get called based on it's type.